# Find a file with an extension .abc, .cde and .fgh and a folder WITHIN a folder

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, parameter-passing

I want to find files with 3 extensions namely .abc, .cde and .fgh. I also would like to find a **folder** named "Bigone" in the directory containing the files with file extensions I mentioned and perform an action on them with `myscript`.. What is the command I should use? Do help. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And add more details please, especially about *perform an action on them with myscript* part

Comment: find -E . -regex '.*\.(abc|cde|fgh)'  -print0 | while read -d $'\0' lp
myscript "$lp"

This works to find the files with the above said extensions. I also would like to find the folder "Bigone'.

Comment: Then why don't you add it to the regex?

Comment: I don't know to add a folder name I'd like to find. Like there can be "Bigone", "Bigone 2",,,etc. How do I modify the command? Do help. Thanks.

Comment: Add to your post what have you tried and what problems are you having with your attemp.

Comment: Pardon me, sir. I’m no pro with this. I’m just getting started with bash scripting. If you could kindly help me with the command I need to use to find the folders AND files In a folder with respective extensions, it’d be helpful. I have not and don’t know what to attempt for this.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the following that you intended to build?
As a preparation, I have set up a simple folder structure that contains some of the files that you mention:

```
~/$ find . -type f \( -name "*.abc" -o -name "*.cde" -o -name "*.fgh" \)
./tmp1/somefile.cde
./tmp1/somefile.fgh
./tmp1/somefile.abc
./tmp2/somefile.abc
~/$ find . -type d -name Bigone
./tmp2/Bigone
```

Furthermore, I simulate your script with the following:

```
~/$ cat myscript 
#!/bin/bash
f=$1
echo "Performing action on file/folder \"$f\""
```

Note that I also considered the possibility of a folder *not* containing the subfolder '*Bigone*' (the command should not fail in that case). Below is a wrapper script that I've built...

```
~/$ cat ./mywrapper 
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f \( -name "*.abc" -o -name "*.cde" -o -name "*.fgh" \) | xargs -n1 ./myscript
find . -type f \( -name "*.abc" -o -name "*.cde" -o -name "*.fgh" \) | xargs dirname | uniq | xargs -n1 -I{} find {} -type d -name Bigone | xargs -n1 ./myscript
```

... and its output when run:

```
~/$ ./mywrapper 
Performing action on file/folder "./tmp1/somefile.cde"
Performing action on file/folder "./tmp1/somefile.fgh"
Performing action on file/folder "./tmp1/somefile.abc"
Performing action on file/folder "./tmp2/somefile.abc"
Performing action on file/folder "./tmp2/Bigone"
```

`find` does the most work here, the rest is just piping the results until they reach your '*myscript*'.

Comment: I want to run myscript on all the files with the extensions I mentioned AND the folders with name "Bigone". If I use your first suggestions, it'll only run on the first two type of extension it finds and exits. I want it to run on ALL of the files with particular extension and folders.

Comment: Oh, sorry so I misunderstood you in the 1st place. I've edited the answer to reflect your comment.